# How to pass any structure to the function?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a problem, maybe you can help me find a good way to solve it. For example i have 2 structures. Both student and teacher have a same field "Name". I want to write a function, to which i can pass student or teacher.

```
struct student
{
    char name[25];
    unsigned int grade;
};

struct teacher
{
    char name[25];
    unsigned int salary[25];
};
```

Function would look like something like that -

```
void findAPersonNamedJohn( anyStruct &struct) {
  for (int i; i < structCount; i++)
    if (!strcmp(struct[i].name, "John"))
      cout << "Found him!";
}
```

Question is: can i somehow write 1 function that offers this functionality, or is the only way to make 2 functions - 1 for student and 1 for teacher.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use char[] array for storing name. In C++ you able to use `std::string` which is 100 times convenient. Also I assume that salary is a number, so why are you using string type for it?

Comment: @LibertyPaul, yes - string makes more sense, thank you! Salary is just an error on my side, i will correct it.
I will leave char, so that people wont have to change their answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either a template function:

```
template<typename T>
void findAPersonNamedJohn( const T *structs, int structCount ) {
    for (int i=0; i < structCount; i++)
        if (!strcmp(structs[i].name, "John"))
            cout << "Found him!";
}
```

Or a common base class for them:

```
struct Base {
    char name[25];
};

struct student: Base {
    unsigned int grade;
};

struct teacher: Base {
    char salary[25];
};

void findAPersonNamedJohn( const Base **structs, int structCount ) {
    for (int i=0; i < structCount; i++)
        if (!strcmp(structs[i]->name, "John"))
            cout << "Found him!";
}
```

Comment: No! The base class example is undefined behaviour and completely wrong in every possible way. The template is correct, if pointless.

Comment: How exactly is it undefined behavior? Are you implying any sort of inheritance is undefined behavior?

Comment: @Puppy Right, slicing. Copy and paste from above. Updated.

Comment: I can't remove my downvote with a good conscience with that raw pointer array indexing shite still present.

Comment: @Puppy I didn't ask you to remove your downvote, so I don't know why you are mentioning it. I've updated the question, that's all. Thank you for noticing the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It is a perfect example of situation when you should use `inheritance`. If you have 2 classes (or structures) with same fields you can move this part from these classes to base class and inherit both from it:

```
struct human{
    char name[25];
};

struct student : public human
{
    unsigned int grade;
};

struct teacher : public human
{
    char salary[25];
};
```

So both `student` and `teacher` will have field `name`

And pass reference to base class into the function:

```
void findAPersonNamedJohn(const human &human) {
    if (!strcmp(human.name, "John"))
      cout << "Found him!";
}
```

This function has no clue about real object type. All it knows is that something with type `human` was passed.

```
int main(){

    student s1;
    strcpy(s1.name, "John");
    s1.grade = 1;

    teacher t1;
    strcpy(s1.name, "Alice");
    s1.grade = 2;

    findAPersonNamedJohn(s1);
    findAPersonNamedJohn(t1);
}
```

Comment: @WhatsUp it is in author's code. Why is it bad to store number in the string is a topic of another question.

Comment: No, this would be terribly undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Puppy Can you please explain where and why?